# Adding values in Oracle SQL database based on certain conditions

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm very stumped on a problem I've come across and am having trouble finding the answer.

I have two tables, one named LEDGER and one named WORKER.  LEDGER contains transactions providing the persons name, item, date, and total amount.  WORKER contains person name only.

I'm trying to write a query that will go (using equi-join) through both LEDGER and WORKER and find instances where a WORKER made a purchase in LEDGER, and output the results.  This basic part is easy and I've already written a query for it:

```
SELECT WORKER.NAME,
LEDGER.ITEM,
LEDGER.AMOUNT
FROM LEDGER, WORKER
WHERE WORKER.NAME = LEDGER.PERSON
  AND LEDGER.ACTION = 'BOUGHT'
GROUP BY WORKER.NAME, LEDGER.ITEM, LEDGER.AMOUNT
ORDER BY WORKER.NAME ASC;
```

The part I'm struggling with is having the SUM of all items appear instead of a list transactions meeting these conditions.  For example, my output is:

```
NAME               ITEM      AMOUNT
ANDREW DYE         COLT      9
ANDREW DYE         COLT      10
ANDREW DYE         HAY       5
ANDREW DYE         HAY       20
ANDREW DYE         LINE      0.75
ANDREW DYE         PIG       2
HELEN BRANDT       BEEF      7.5
PETER LAWSON       BEEF      6.5
VICTORIA LYNN      BEEF      6.9
```

Instead of this, I want only the total amounts combining all item amounts in one row, like this:

```
NAME               TOTAL_AMOUNT
ANDREW DYE         46.75
HELEN BRANDT       7.5
PETER LAWSON       6.5
VICTORIA LYNN      6.9
```

I hope the question makes sense, and thanks so much for any answers.

Comment: I removed the mysql and sql-server tags, because the question is explicitly about Oracle.

Comment: Where does the `item` value come from in your desired results?  If the total is for all items, why include a specific item?

Comment: Sorry about the tag, thanks for fixing.  Sorry about the confusion, the final query should only display NAME and AMOUNT(Total amount really).  I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT WORKER.NAME,
MAX(LEDGER.ITEM),
SUM(LEDGER.AMOUNT)
FROM LEDGER, WORKER
WHERE WORKER.NAME = LEDGER.PERSON
  AND LEDGER.ACTION = 'BOUGHT'
GROUP BY WORKER.NAME
ORDER BY WORKER.NAME ASC;
```

Comment: @user2669843 Glad it worked for you! Accepting the answer, is great way of expressing thanks!